# I want to simplify this javascript code. There are many children elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was trying to make this menu,

when clicked first item,
[menu pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0abKr.png)

when clicked second item,
[menu pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6SLi.png)

i have created styles for class 'on' in style sheet.

```
colorItems = document.querySelector('#color').children[1]

colorItems.children[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    colorItems.children[0].classList.toggle('on')
    colorItems.children[1].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[2].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[3].classList.remove('on')
})
colorItems.children[1].addEventListener('click', () => {
    colorItems.children[0].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[1].classList.toggle('on')
    colorItems.children[2].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[3].classList.remove('on')
})
colorItems.children[2].addEventListener('click', () => {
    colorItems.children[0].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[1].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[2].classList.toggle('on')
    colorItems.children[3].classList.remove('on')
})
colorItems.children[3].addEventListener('click', () => {
    colorItems.children[0].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[1].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[2].classList.remove('on')
    colorItems.children[3].classList.toggle('on')
})
```

Comment: share your html code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your code here is a solution:

**#color** as i see its your **parent** container and its has **children** lets assume they are buttons, you need to select the childrens using **querySelectorAll** and loop through them, whenever you click on a **button** you should add **.on** css class to the **clicked button** and remove this class from its **siblings** here is workable example:

```js
let colorItems = document.querySelectorAll('#color button');

colorItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        colorItems.forEach(i => i != item ? i.classList.remove('on') : i.classList.add('on'));
    });
});
```

```css
.on {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="color">
    <button>red</button>
    <button>blue</button>
    <button>white</button>
    <button>black</button>
</div>
```